# Comparing Two Sets of Date Ranges in SQL

Tags: sql, db2, sas

I have two sets of data with different date ranges.

```
Tbl 1:  
ID, Date_Start, Date_End
1, 2010-01-01, 2010-01-09
1, 2010-01-10, 2010-01-19
1, 2010-01-30, 2010-01-31

Tbl 2:
ID, Date_Start, Date_End
1, 2010-01-01, 2010-01-04
1, 2010-01-08, 2010-01-17
1, 2010-01-30, 2010-01-31
```

I'd like to find cases date ranges do not entirely overlap date ranges in Tbl 2.  So for instance, in this example, I'd like output that looks something like this --

```
Output:
ID, Gap_Start, Gap_End
1, 2010-01-05, 2010-01-07
1, 2010-01-18, 2010-01-19
```

Date ranges will never overlap within a table.  To do this, I'm using either DB2 SQL or SAS.  Unfortunately, the datasets are big enough (millions of records) that I can't just brute force it.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following on from Jon of All Trades' approach, this is a more completed solution. The crucial features are:

1. Use an [auxiliary calendar table](http://web.archive.org/web/20070611150639/http://sqlserver2000.databases.aspfaq.com/why-should-i-consider-using-an-auxiliary-calendar-table.html), which is just a list of all dates.
2. From the calendar table, JOIN to Tbl1 to get a list of dates which are in range.
3. Also do an [anti-JOIN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra#Antijoin) to Tbl2 to get only the dates which aren't in Tbl2's ranges.
4. I've enclosed those results in a [Common Table Expression (CTE)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_table_expressions) called OutDates.
5. Define another CTE based on OutDates to get just the dates which start a gap; call this EarliestDates.
6. Define another CTE based on OutDates to get just the dates which end a gap; call this LatestDates.
7. JOIN EarliestDates and LatestDates to put each gap into a single row.

---

```
WITH
OutDates(ID, dt) AS
( SELECT Tbl1.ID, Calendar.dt FROM Calendar
INNER JOIN Tbl1 ON Calendar.dt BETWEEN Tbl1.Date_Start AND Tbl1.Date_End
LEFT OUTER JOIN Tbl2 ON Calendar.dt BETWEEN Tbl2.Date_Start AND Tbl2.Date_End
WHERE Tbl2.ID IS NULL
)
,
EarliestDates AS
(   SELECT earliest.ID, earliest.dt FROM OutDates earliest
    LEFT OUTER JOIN OutDates nonesuch_earlier ON DateAdd(day, -1, earliest.dt) = nonesuch_earlier.dt
    WHERE nonesuch_earlier.ID IS NULL
)
,
LatestDates AS
(   SELECT latest.ID, latest.dt FROM OutDates latest
    LEFT OUTER JOIN OutDates nonesuch_later ON DATEADD(day, 1, latest.dt) = nonesuch_later.dt
    WHERE nonesuch_later.ID IS NULL
)
SELECT rangestart.ID, rangestart.dt AS Gap_Start, rangeend.dt AS Gap_End 
 FROM EarliestDates rangestart JOIN LatestDates rangeend
 ON rangestart.dt <= rangeend.dt
LEFT OUTER JOIN EarliestDates nonesuch_inner1
 ON nonesuch_inner1.dt <= rangeend.dt AND nonesuch_inner1.dt > rangestart.dt 
LEFT OUTER JOIN LatestDates nonesuch_inner2
 ON nonesuch_inner2.dt >= rangestart.dt AND nonesuch_inner2.dt < rangeend.dt
WHERE nonesuch_inner1.dt IS NULL AND nonesuch_inner2.dt IS NULL
```

This is a working implementation using Sql Server syntax for the common table expressions, but it should be easy to convert to DB2 syntax. I don't know how well it well scale to be honest, I've only tested it with a very small dataset.

Comment: I tried this version, and it seemed to have a few issues.  First, my rewritten version --

Comment: Thanks for the response!  --  The issue I encountered was that it seemed to not handle multiple gaps of a single day well (it would have one record with 09-01-2009 to 09-01-2009, and then another record with 09-01-2009 to 09-01-2010).  This mainly came up because we had a system issue that kept randomly putting holes on the first day of a month.

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean. Is it Tbl1 which has a record with a date range 09/01/2009 - 09/01/2009, or is that a gap which my SQL is correctly/incorrectly returning?

Comment: I have two one day gaps in table 2.  One of the gaps is 09/01/2009, and the other on 09/01/2010.  This SQL seems to be having issues with that.

Comment: Found it and fixed it. In the last anti-joins I'd got a < where I needed a <=, and a > where I needed a >=.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is the efficient and general solution for all the cases. Under certain circumstances, however, we can figure out some efficient ones. For instance, below assumes that: (1) datasets one and two have the same set of ids in the same order; and (2) there are relatively short possible date ranges (assumed here to be all the dates in the year of 2010 only). Notice that one input range may generate two gaps.

```
/* test data */
data one;
  input id1 (start1 finish1) (:anydtdte.);
  format start1 finish1 e8601da.;
cards;
1 2010-01-01 2010-01-09
1 2010-01-10 2010-01-19
1 2010-01-30 2010-01-31
2 2010-01-02 2010-01-10
;
run;

data two;
  input id2 (start2 finish2) (:anydtdte.);
  format start2 finish2 e8601da.;
cards;
1 2010-01-01 2010-01-04
1 2010-01-08 2010-01-17
1 2010-01-30 2010-01-31
2 2010-01-05 2010-01-06
;
run;


/* assumptions:
   (1) datasets one and two have the same set of ids in the same
       sorted order;
   (2) only possible dates are in the year of 2010
*/
%let minDate = %sysevalf('01jan2010'd - 1);
%let maxDate = %sysevalf('31dec2010'd + 1);

data gaps;

  array inRange[&minDate:&maxDate] _temporary_;
  array covered[&minDate:&maxDate] _temporary_;
  do i = &minDate to &maxDate; inRange[i] = 0; covered[i] = 0; end;

  do until (last.id1);
    set one;
    by id1;
    do i = start1 to finish1; inRange[i] = 1; end;
  end;

  do until (last.id2);
    set two;
    by id2;
    do i =  start2 to finish2; covered[i] = 1; end;
  end;

  format startGap finishGap e8601da.;
  startGap = .;
  finishGap = .;
  do i = &minDate+1 to &maxDate;
    if inRange[i] and not covered[i] and missing(startGap) then startGap = i;
    if (covered[i] or not inRange[i]) and not missing(startGap) and not covered[i-1] then do;
      finishGap = i - 1;
      output;
      call missing(startGap, finishGap);
      keep id1 startGap finishGap;
    end;
  end;     
run;

/* check */
proc print data=gaps noobs;
run; 
/* on lst 
id1     startGap     finishGap

 1     2010-01-05    2010-01-07
 1     2010-01-18    2010-01-19
 2     2010-01-02    2010-01-04
 2     2010-01-07    2010-01-10
*/
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not a complete solution, as it returns a list of dates rather than ranges, but maybe it will be of use:

```
SELECT
  R1.ID, D.Date
FROM
  #Ranges1 AS R1
  INNER JOIN Dates AS D ON D.Date BETWEEN R1.StartDate AND R1.EndDate
EXCEPT
SELECT
  R2.ID, D.Date
FROM
  #Ranges2 AS R2
  INNER JOIN Dates AS D ON D.Date BETWEEN R2.StartDate AND R2.EndDate
```

Note that this solution requires a dates table: a table with one record per day, for all the dates you're likely to use.  It has the advantages of being succinct, and handling overlapping date ranges (not necessary in your case, but maybe for the next guy).

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, this is the method I ended up using.  I think you could do it in pure SQL, but it got horrifically ugly and difficult to debug.

Step 1 -- I consolidated the date ranges in both datasets.  This means that something like

```
ID, Start_Date, End_Date
1,  2010-01-01, 2010-01-31
1,  2010-02-01, 2010-02-28
```

got transformed into this --

```
ID, Start_Date, End_Date
1,  2010-01-01, 2010-02-28.
```

The query I used to produce this was --

```
WITH Cte_recomb (Id, Start_date, End_date, Hopcount) AS
        (SELECT Id,
                Start_date,
                End_date,
                1 AS Hopcount
         FROM Table1
         UNION ALL
         SELECT Cte_recomb.Id,
                Cte_recomb.Start_date,
                Table1.End_date,
                (Recomb.Hopcount + 1) AS Hopcount
         FROM Cte_recomb, Table1
         WHERE (Cte_recomb.Id = Table1.Id) AND
               (Cte_recomb.End_date + 1 day = Table1.Start_date)),
     Cte_maxenddate AS
        (SELECT Id,
                Start_date,
                Max (End_date) AS End_date
         FROM Cte_recomb
         GROUP BY Id, Start_date
         ORDER BY Id, Start_date)
SELECT Maxend.*
FROM    Cte_maxenddate AS Maxend
     LEFT JOIN
        Cte_recomb AS Nextrec
     ON (Nextrec.Id = Maxend.Id) AND
        (Nextrec.Start_date < Maxend.Start_date) AND
        (Nextrec.End_date >= Maxend.End_date)
WHERE Nextrec.Id IS NULL;
```

Step 2 --

I produced another dataset that created a record for every overlap between the two datasets.  You'll need an additional step to find cases where a given record in Table1 doesn't have a corresponding record in Table2 at all.

```
SELECT Table1.Id,
       Table1.Start_date AS Table1_start_date,
       Table1.End_date AS Table1_end_date,
       Table2.Start_date AS Table2_start_date,
       Table2.End_date AS Table2_end_date
FROM    Table1
     INNER JOIN
        Table2
     ON (Table1.Plcy_id_sk = Id) AND
        ( (Table1.Start_date BETWEEN Table2.Start_date AND Table2.End_date) OR
         (Table2.Start_date  BETWEEN Table1.Start_date AND Table1.End_date)) AND
        ( (Table1.Start_date <> Table2.Start_date) OR
         (Table1.End_date    <> Table2.End_date))
ORDER BY Table1.Id, Table1.Start_date, Table2.Start_date;
```

Step 3 --

I take the above dataset, and run the following SAS job.  I tried to do this in pure SQL with recursive queries, but it got uglier and uglier every time I looked at it.

```
Data Table1_Gaps;
  Set Table1_Compare;
  By ID Table1_Start_Date Table2_Start_Date;
  format Gap_Start_Date yymmdd10.;
  format Gap_End_Date   yymmdd10.;
  format Old_Start_Date yymmdd10.;
  format Old_End_Date   yymmdd10.;
  Retain Old_Start_Date Old_End_Date;
  IF (Table2_End_Date = .) then do;
      Gap_Start_Date = Table1_Start_Date;
      Gap_End_Date   = Table1_End_Date;
      output;
  end;
  else do;
    If (Table2_Start_Date > Table1_Start_Date) then do;
      if first.Table1_Start_Date then do;
        Gap_Start_Date = Table1_Start_Date;
        Gap_End_Date   = Table2_Start_Date - 1;
        output;
      end;
      else do;
        Gap_Start_Date = Old_End_Date + 1;
        Gap_End_Date   = Table2_Start_Date - 1;
        output;
      end;
    end;
    If (Table2_End_Date < Table1_End_Date) then do;
      if Last.Table1_Start_Date then do;
        Gap_Start_Date = Table2_End_Date + 1;
        Gap_End_Date   = Table1_End_Date;
        output;
      end;
    end;
  end;
  Old_Start_Date = Table2_Start_Date;
  Old_End_Date   = Table2_End_Date;
  drop Old_Start_Date Old_End_Date;
run;
```

I haven't verified it entirely yet, but this approach does seem to have given me the results I wanted.  Any thoughts?